# Как получить имя пользователя, который открыл файл?

Tags: vbscript

в VBScript
пытаюсь создать подключение к excel файлу. но эта таблица лежит на сервере, иногда эта таблица бывает занята другим пользователем. как я могу получить имя пользователя кто занял данную таблицу? уведомление во вложении.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно этот код поможет, проверить правда негде. [Исходник](http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?id=787)

> Скрипт выводит список открытых по сети файлов на файл-сервере и имена
>   пользователей домена, открывших эти файлы.

```
ServerName = "ComputerName"
'==============================================================================
On Error Resume Next
Set FileService = GetObject("WinNT://" & ServerName & "/LanmanServer")
For Each Res In FileService.Resources
    WScript.Echo Res.Get("User") & " " & Res.Get("Path")
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

> В качестве ServerName можно использовать "." (текущий компьютер).

Comment: когда получаю данные о открытых файлов по сети показывает что гость открыл данный файл. но не указывает пользователя